# Jquery: change html knowing node inside

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

I've this code:

```
<p> &nbsp &nbsp <span> text </span> &nbsp &nbsp </p>
```

how to delete second and third &nbsp of p, through the node span?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get child nodes of `p` and remove space from text nodes

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

var nodes = p.childNodes;

nodes[0].textContent = nodes[0].textContent.replace(' ', '');
nodes[2].textContent = nodes[2].textContent.replace(' ', '');
```

```html
<p>&nbsp &nbsp <span> text </span> &nbsp &nbsp</p>
```